# How to delete one copy of Ruby? (M1 Mac with zsh)

Tags: ruby, apple-m1, rbenv

Running `which -a ruby` returns me the following:

```
/Users/USERNAME/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/Users/USERNAME/.rbenv/shims/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

The `/usr/bin/ruby`, I presume, is the pre-installed version of Ruby that ships with M1 Macs.

The double copies of `/Users/USERNAME/.rbenv/shims/ruby` are what I'm concerned about. Does this mean that I installed two duplicate copies of ruby? If that is the case, how can I uninstall one of them?

The double copies of `/Users/USERNAME/.rbenv/shims/ruby` are what I'm concerned about. Does this mean that I installed two duplicate copies of ruby? If that is the case, how can I uninstall one of them?

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67036/295479

Answer (score 0):

> Does this mean that I installed two duplicate copies of ruby?

No. `which` outputs file paths, which are identified by their string representation. So it's not possible for the two `/Users/USERNAME/.rbenv/shims/ruby` paths to refer to two different installation of Ruby. Therefore you only have the default ruby and the rbenv one.

The only "concern" here is that your shell config is a little redundant since it has two ways of finding the rbenv Ruby, but realistically that won't cause any issues.